# Convert unknow Bits from Byte array to int

Tags: c#, .net, binary, bit-manipulation, math

```
private int bitToIntParser
(byte[] recordData, int byteOffset, int byteLength, int bitOffset, int bitLength)
        {
            //step1:Byte[] selectedBytes = recordData[byteOffset to byteOffset + Length]  
            //step2:BitArray selectedBits=selectdBytes.bits[bitOffset to bitOffset+bitLength]
            //step3:convert selectedBit to Int          
        }
```

The above function should be able to extract `bytes[byteOffset]` to `bytes[byteOffset+length]` from `recordData` and then extract `bit[bitOffset]` to `bit[bitOffset+BitLength]` from the previous result and convert it to `int`.

Can any one please help me with this?

Comment: for step1 I have used byte[] workingSet = new byte[4];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(recordData, byteOffset, workingSet, 0, length); but then I'm not sure how to extract requested bits from it , I tried shifting but couldn't get result

Comment: Any constraints on the bitOffset and bitLength parameters?

Comment: @Henk : it should not be more than 32 bits so we can use BitVector32

Comment: What the correct result for such input?
recordData: {00001111b 11110000b}
byteOffset:0 byteLength:2
bitOffset:4 bitLength:8

Comment: @Alex : selectedBits = 11111111 & result = 255 , and for your 2nd question byteLength wont be larger than what we need like in your example if bitlength = 2 then byteLength would be 1 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, this has turned into some very messy code. We'll have to do the bit shifting manually, since you could *potentially* involve more than four bytes in this operation depending upon your bit location. Assuming little endian byte order (LSB first):

```
// No need for byte length, since you're passing in a bit count
private int ParseByteArray(byte[] recordData, int offset, int bitOffset, 
       int bitCount)
{
    if(bitCount < 1 || bitCount > 32) 
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("bitCount must be between 1 and 32");
    }

     int output = 0;
    int byteCount = 0;

    byte rightMask = (byte)(((1 << bitOffset) - 1) << (8 - bitOffset));
    byte leftMask = (byte)(255 ^ rightMask);

    while (bitCount > 0)
    {
        byte data = (byte)(((recordData[offset] & leftMask) << bitOffset) + 
                    ((bitCount > 8 - bitOffset ? 
                    ((recordData[offset + 1] & rightMask) >> (8 - bitOffset)) 
                    : 0)));

        if (bitCount < 8)
        {
            byte mask = (byte)(255^((1 << (8 - bitCount)) - 1));

            data = (byte)((data & mask) >> (8 - bitCount));
        }

        offset++;

        output += data << (byteCount * 8);

        byteCount++;

        bitCount -= Math.Min(bitCount, 8);
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: ParseByteArray(new byte[]{0xFF, 0xA},1,4,3) // fail (

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the byteLength and bitLength are redundant (the offsets too).

But as it stands, I would say:

- make an 8 byte intermediate array
- copy byteLength  bytes (1..4) to that array, probably from offset 7-byteLength
- use BitConvertor.ToInt64() to turn it into a `long`
- value = (int) (longValue >> bitOffset)

This still has open ends (do you expect signed or unsigned int32's ? )

I didn't test this, you may have endian issues as well.

Comment: `byteLength` is redundant, but not necessarily `bitOffset`. While you could represent the entire offset in bits (making it genuinely redundant), I took it as the bit offset *within a byte* where the number starts, meaning that the final 8-bitOffset bits come from the first 8-bitOffset bits of the following byte.

Comment: @Adam: byteOffset and bitOffset could be easily combined. The lengths are more strongly related. It would be a 'nicer' interface with just a bit-range

Comment: I need the byte length because of performance, the recordData might be a large array . and I also need BitLength because we may just want bit 2 and 3 from a byte so we will call the function with bitoffset = 2 and bitLength = 2 , i think the way you explained won't work in case like what I just explained

Comment: @Asna: You will always need to have `byteLength == (bitLength+7) / 8`. But you're right, my solution doesn't mask of the left bits. I'll leave it at this.